# Bytecode: Does it Reveal What Language it Was Programmed In?

Tags: solidity, bytecode, vyper, deployed-bytecode

Does EVM bytecode have some indication to what high-level language it was programmed in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm really not an expert in this but I would imagine (mostly) no, especially if optimization is turned on. There is no need for the bytecode to include any indications of the original language so including such details would be a waste of space - each extra byte costs gas.

However I might imagine different language compilers to exhibit certain characteristics. For example compiler A stores function `myFunc` in a different location than compiler B or something similar. This way the gas cost is the same. But this is just guessing, I really don't know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility might be to retrieve the source code from the IPFS hash embedded in the bytecode. But this requires the developer to have published the source code on IPFS.

[See docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.7.1/metadata.html) on metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not definitively.

### Solidity

Solidity makes use of a free memory pointer, setting this pointer is the first thing Solidity bytecode does, meaning that Solidity contracts almost always (I think always tbh, but figure I'll hedge) start with opcode 60 (`PUSH1`), and usually pushing the value 80 onto the stack, meaning they start with `0x6080`. It is entirely possible for a non-Solidity contract to start with `0x6080` or even `0x60806040` (see below), but it's a pretty solid sign that it's a Solidity contract.

Tangent: In a funny little twist, Manifold Studio [realized](https://twitter.com/richerd/status/1521284026287370242) that their contracts  also continue by `PUSH1`ing 40 onto the stack next (yielding `0x60806040`), so they brute forced function arguments to be able to produce a function selector that corresponds to it using `atInversebrah` as the function name (the full signature was `atInversebrah(bytes28,(int56),int200,(bytes23),(int160,bytes29),uint208,uint240,int168,(bytes18,bytes30[]))`, though if you'll check [4byte](https://www.4byte.directory/signatures/?bytes4_signature=0x60806040), someone has since brute forced a more convenient one). In reality, a large number of Solidity contracts have this pattern (I've heard the majority, but don't have the data). The result of this was that if you deployed a Solidity contract, MetaMask and other wallets/apps that used 4byte would register it as a function interaction with a function called `atInversebrah`. This is no longer the case, as MetaMask treated this as a bug instead of a feature ([source](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/pull/14598)). Go figure.

</ tangent>

### Vyper

I looked around some Vyper contracts, and it happens to be that they all started with opcode 61 (`PUSH2`), but pushing completely different values onto the stack. 2 were followed by a `JUMP` (opcode 56), and one with `PUSH1`:

[Uniswap v1](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc0a47dFe034B400B47bDaD5FecDa2621de6c4d95#code): `0x6103f056`

[Yearn WBTC Vault](https://etherscan.io/address/0xcb550a6d4c8e3517a939bc79d0c7093eb7cf56b5#code): `0x614c3456`

[Curve Factory Plain Pool (implementation)](https://etherscan.io/address/0x4a4d7868390ef5cac51cda262888f34bd3025c3f#code): `0x617a6960`

Obviously n=3 isn't enough for serious correlation, but it leads to a suspicion that Vyper contracts start with opcode 61. So will any other contract that starts with `PUSH2` though.

### Everything Else

I don't have any data handy for any of the others, would be interested in knowing of any actual deployments in Yulp or Huff.

If you have any additional information to update this with, please add it in comments! I'm fairly certain we can do better than this, and see this as just the beginning.