# How to have solidity output as minimal assembler-close bytecode as possible?

Tags: solidity, evm, assembly, bytecode, optimization

While as indicated in [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/131403/2256) it is probably impossible to have Solidity [optimize](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/internals/optimizer.html) away the free memory pointer and it's initialization causing the bytecode to start with `0x6080`, I was wondering if it is nonetheless possible to approach something closer to e.g. the [ERC-1167 Minimal Proxy Contract](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1167#specification) `0x363d3d373d3d3d363d73bebebebebebebebebebebebebebebebebebebebe5af43d82803e903d91602b57fd5bf3`, e.g. at least skipping any function selector?